# docker image build getting check sum error - Rpmdb checksum is invalid: dCDPT

Tags: docker, centos

Details of the error :

We have a custom docker image and we build on top of Cent OS 7 which is the base image . While build image happening got this error .

Rpmdb checksum is invalid: dCDPT(pkg checksums): dbus-libs.x86_64 1:1.10.24-7.el7 - u
  _[0m 
  The command '/bin/sh -c yum clean all       && yum -y swap fakesystemd systemd     && yum clean all && yum -y update     && yum clean all' returned a non-zero code: 1
07/10/18 [04:54:22]# TRACE       : Error Trace:-

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same issue. This worked for me :

```
`RUN touch /var/lib/rpm/* \    
 && yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`
```

Comment: touching the files solved the problem for me too. Do you know what the root cause of the error message is? Why/how does this fix the problem?

Comment: would `yum -y update` be a better thing to run vs `touch /var/lib/rpm/*` (assuming that fixes the problem), since I would think the update would also touch those files and would make sure it had the latest repo data?

Answer (score 2):

Installing `yum-plugin-ovl` should resolve your issue. You can simply try

`yum install yum-plugin-ovl` before installing `dbus-libs`.

Comment: This solution didn't help: the problem was occurring despite this plugin was already installed. See below answer about using `touch`.

Answer (score 2):

This might be something related to damage in RPM’s database. In this case it’s necessary to rebuild it before installing, like:

`RUN rpm —-rebuilddb && yum install -y …`

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`RUN yum install -y package; yum clean all`

beware that this equals `RUN yum install -y package || true`, so make sure package is installed correctly before you workaround it